# CSS Text gradient, Opera degradation

Tags: css, opera, graceful-degradation

I use this and it works fine on webkit browsers, and simple on firefox. But Opera gives weird results.

The css i'm using:

```
color:@coreDarkBlue;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cccc66, #cc0033);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Any hints on how i can default to color: @coreDarkBlue on opera too? I'm assuming opera does not support the effect after a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

```
you are missing some opera support..


check this e.g.

background: -o-linear-gradient(#cccc66, #cc0033);
-o-background-clip: text;
-o-text-fill-color: transparent; /* Opera 11.10+ */
```

and if you wanna get real crazy and have some IE support..

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccc66', endColorstr='#cc0033',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */